# Using similar color on points and lines in ArcMap or FME?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, fme-form

I have two feature classes/shapefiles. One containing points and one containing lines.

They have both a field called Gate_number. I can use Symbology to give every point with the same gate_number similar color, and i can do the same with the shp containing lines.

My problem is that I want to have the same color on the lines and ponits which have similar gate_number.

Every point with gate_number=2155 should be green and ever line with gate_number=2155 should be the same color green.

Can this be done in ArcMap or FME?

Answer (score 2):

Sort of. If you use the same colour ramp you will get the same colours. However, if there is a difference between the unique values (I assume you are using the unique values renderer), like for instance value 999 exists only on the points, you will get a mismatch. If you are using the classified renderer then you can reproduce the classes with the same colour ramp and get an exact match; you would find it difficult as there would be little to no difference between 2155 and 2156.

You can build a style file and then match to symbols in the style where value 2155 is represented by a marker symbol and line symbol but these style files are just as tedious, if not more tedious, than changing each symbol interactively.

There is no easy way to do this in ArcMap, but once it's done save as a layer file and then use it to colour future instances by importing their symbology.

Answer (score 0):

There is a transformer on the FME Store called the GradedColorizer. To me it looks like this might be what you need. I think it's worth a try.

http://fmestore.safe.com/transformers/GradedColorizer.htm